# Trouble with checking type of user control

Tags: vb.net, combobox, user-controls, controls

I have a group of ComboBoxs that I am looking to bind to a datasource.

There are going to be upwards of 200 ComboBoxs all being bound to the same source and so I am looking at doing this using a loop to go through all the controls on the form, find appropriate controls and do binding.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
For Each uxControl As UserControl In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf (uxControl) Is ComboBox Then
            Dim tbControl As ComboBox = DirectCast(uxControl, ComboBox)
            If tbControl.Name.StartsWith("cmbDesk") Then
                tbControl.DataSource = myDS
                tbControl.DisplayMember = "employee_id"
                tbControl.ValueMember = "name"
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

There currently is no other code apart from the SQL to fill the DataSet.
The ComboBoxs are in a tab page so there are other controls on the form.

At the moment I am getting the error message :

> Expression of type 'System.Windows.Forms.UserControl' can never be of
>   type 'System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox'.

Any help in resolving this.

Comment: A `UserControl` is used to design a group of controls using the Visual Studio designer, whereas `Control` is the base class for all controls. If you're only looking to iterate all check boxes on your form and they're not in user controls your code should be: `For Each uxControl As Control In Me.Controls`.

Comment: Or even better, remove the `If TypeOf (uxControl) Is ComboBox Then` statement and change your loop to: `For Each cbControl As ComboBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of ComboBox)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
For Each uxControl As UserControl In Me.Controls
```

to

```
For Each uxControl As Control In Me.Controls
```

A [`UserControl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.usercontrol?view=netframework-4.7.2) provides an empty control that can be used to create other controls.

Like already mentioned in comments you could also use some LINQ to get rid of the line
`If TypeOf (uxControl) Is ComboBox Then` and change the `For Each`-loop as follows:

```
For Each comboBox As ComboBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of ComboBox)
    If comboBox.Name.StartsWith("cmbDesk") Then
        comboBox.DataSource = myDS
        comboBox.DisplayMember = "employee_id"
        comboBox.ValueMember = "name"
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Hi MatSnow. Thanks for the change to the syntax for the control. Also a shout out to Visual Vincent above for the LINQ code to tidy up the code it work great. Now all I need to do is create 150 ComboBox on 3 tab pages arranged to mirror the layout of the 3 floors in our building.